# HTML: How to align multiple elements within a list?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a nested list, and I want to attach some buttons to each entry. But the alignment is very wired. See [JSFIDDLE example here](http://jsfiddle.net/1ha04a3r/3/).

Basically I want all buttons positioned just like `button1`. What should I do?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have a ul that's  child of another ul.

Comment: @JoeDeRose: not the way he did it, he needs to add ul inside li, not ul inside ul

Comment: I think you need to be a little more clear in this criticism: The child `<ul>` tags need to be inside an `<li>` tag. See the Nesting list example at Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FElement%2Ful#Nesting_list

Comment: @JoeDeRose Got it. Thanks for correction.

Comment: Please inlcude your code in the question, a fiddle is great but don't makes us go looking for your code, include it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your CSS:

```
li { clear: right; }
```

This will also work:

```
.right {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
```

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1ha04a3r/5/

Comment: That's AMAZING!! Could you explain it a little bit? I saw on w3school that **The clear property specifies which side(s) of an element other floating elements are not allowed**. But I still don't really understand what happened.

Comment: @wlnirvana - The experts would be better able to explain this. This slideshare is very informative about the float and clear property: http://www.slideshare.net/maxdesign/css-floats-explained. Slide 62 begins explaining the clear property.

Answer (score 2):

you can add clear right to your li element or if you need more fine tuning for position, try this:

**HTML (to correct yours)**

```
<ul>
    <li>test <button class='right'>button1</button></li>
    <li>test <button class='right'>button2</button></li>
   <li> <ul>
        <li>test <button class='right'>button3</button></li>
        <li>test <button class='right'>button4</button></li>
       </ul></li>
    <li><ul>
            <li>test <button class='right'>button6</button></li>
            <li>test <button class='right'>button6</button></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.right {
    position:absolute; right:10px; top:2px;
}
li{ width:100%; position:relative; padding:5px 0;}
```

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mq103kjL/)

Answer (score 0):

the alignment is very wired because you are using "float:right" in css. remove it then it will work and you can use the css class to modify your list padding and position.

### HTML Code

```
 <ul>
        <li>test <button class='right'>button1</button></li>
        <li>test <button class='right'>button2</button></li>
        <ul>
            <li>test <button class='right'>button3</button></li>
            <li>test <button class='right'>button4</button></li>
            <ul>
                <li>test <button class='right'>button6</button></li>
                <li>test <button class='right'>button6</button></li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </ul>
```

### css

```
 li{ width:100%; padding:2px auto;}
```

*you can use position relative